# continuous map of connected set is connected, example: Proving the connectedness of this set.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

I thought I would try to use this to prove connectedness in this set if possible:
$$\{(x,y)\mid 1<x^2+y^2<4\}$$
$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$

So since $(1,4)$ is connected in $\mathbb R$ so it this set, as my function is continuous? Could I do the same with $\{(x,y,z)\mid 1<x^2+y^2+z^2<4\}$?

I realized this is pre-image, which doesnt have to be true. But is this function valid, or continuous:

$$f(x)=\{(u,v)\mid u^2+v^2=x^2, x \in (1,2)\}$$

Comment: It looks like the fact you would need is that the preimage of a connected set is connected. However, that's not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would solve this by considering the "polar coordinates" map: $g(x, y) = (r(x, y), \theta(x, y))$. This is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse (on the area of interest), so in fact we only need to consider $(1, 4) \times [0, 2 \pi) \subset \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} \times [0, 2 \pi)$.

This is connected: it's a product of connected sets.

Comment: May I ask if this was a ring type of elipse. How would you form the polar coordinates then ?

Comment: And another question, say it was a ring in 3d, im guessing spherical coordinates would be need. But how ?

Comment: At that point, I'd probably say "look, it's obvious that polar coordinates exist, but I can't be bothered to show them to you explicitly" :P

Comment: I thank you for your idea :D

Answer (score 1):

As was stated in the comments, the preimage of a connected set need not be connected even if the mapping in question is continuous.

In this case I would most likely try to prove that the set you are considering is path-connected. Indeed if we look at the set you have described it is equivalent to
$$ \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 < |x| < 2\}$$
If you draw this set on paper you will notice it is simply a 2-dimensional donut! Next I would try and come up with a way to connect any two points in the donut. When choosing this path make sure that you know how to prove that each part of your path is a part of your set!

> One such path between two points could consist of a shift toward the origin such that when you shift the point by a relevant angle we get to the second point!